# What worms devour the body?

Tags: entomology, etymology

I was reading [this site](http://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/acne/adult-10/slideshow-adult-acne) which broached **comedones**, an esoteric word to me; so I thought to look up its etymology which I find exceptionally singular and peculiar (I would have never guessed that the word originated from *`to eat up`* !) :

> [Etmyonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=comedo&searchmode=none): "blackhead," etc., 1866, from Latin comedo "glutton," from comedere `"to eat up"` (see [comestible](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=comestible&allowed_in_frame=0)). **A name formerly given to worms that devour the body**; transferred in medical use to secretions that resemble them.

Footnote: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/comedo?q=comedones) also offers an etymology.

Comment: How the body is degraded depends entirely on the manner of body preparation and burial.

Comment: And the "worms" most likely to eat a corpse are probably maggots.

Comment: Maggots that typically feed on the carrion can be from different flies species, the most common in Europe are from the family of Calliphoridae and Sarcophagidae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maggot typically feeds on carrion. A maggot is the larva of a fly and usually  particular to the larvae of *Brachyceran* flies, such as houseflies, cheese flies, and blowflies.
[image: maggot]

Interestingly decomposition from maggots has a lot of use in forensic science as the presence or development of maggots on a corpse can be useful to a forensic entomologists to determine the approximate time of death. Depending on the species and the conditions, maggots may be observed on a body within 24 hours. The eggs are laid on the body and when the eggs hatch, the maggots move towards their preferred conditions and begin to feed. Insects are usually useful  25–80 hours post mortem and is contingent on temp humidity and oxygen availability. After 80 hours, this method becomes less reliable.